# Getting Error when the CORS is going to activated in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I just tried to activate the CORS with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.But it gives the following error message

[image]

Comment: I'd try this "attempt to execute failed steps manually via Method editor"... [Set up an API Gateway Method Response Using the API Gateway Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-set-up-method-using-console.html#how-to-method-response-settings-console)... then check your IAM permissions if you're not using root user [Control Access for Managing an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-create-and-manage-api.html)

Comment: Does the (red) ⚠️ provide any tool-tip text if you hovertmouse-over or click them?